# Vim folding without end markers

Tags: vim

I'd like to fold text between beginning markers like:

```
//// Block 1

... some code 1 ...

//// Block 2

... some code 2 ...
```

where `////` would be used as the beginning marker and folding `//// Block 1` would fold to the line before `//// Block 2`.

Is this something that's possible?

It doesn't like it if I set `foldmarker` without an ending parameter and it folds too much if I use `////` as both the beginning and ending markers.

I could manually create folds with `zf`, but those are file dependent and break if you change it.

Comment: Interesting. What have you tried so far?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can write your own fold expression like this:

```
function! BlockFolds()
   let thisline = getline(v:lnum)
   if match(thisline, '^\/\/\/\/ Block') >= 0
      return ">1"
   else
      return "="
   endif
endfunction

setlocal foldmethod=expr
setlocal foldexpr=BlockFolds()
```

If you source it in vim you will get the desired effect:

[image: demo]

Obviously you can source it in your `.vimrc` or based on file extension.
You can understand how custom fold expressions work here: http://vimcasts.org/episodes/writing-a-custom-fold-expression/